# awk reading in values

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Hello the following code is used by me to split a file

```
BEGIN{body=0}
!body && /^\/\/$/    {body=1}
body  && /^\[/       {print > "first_"FILENAME}
body  && /^pos/{$1="";print > "second_"FILENAME}
body  && /^[01]+/    {print > "third_"FILENAME}
body  && /^\[[0-9]+\]/ {
  print > "first_"FILENAME
  print substr($0, 2, index($0,"]")-2) > "fourth_"FILENAME
}
```

the file looks like here

```
 header
//
SeqT: {"POS-s":174.683, "time":0.0130084}
SeqT: {"POS-s":431.49, "time":0.0221447}
[2.04545e+2]:0.00843832,469:0.0109533):0.00657864,((((872:0.00120503,((980:0.0001);
[29]:((962:0.000580339,930:0.000580339):0.00543993);
absolute:
gthcont: 5 4 2 1 3 4 543 5  67 657  78 67 8  5645 6 
01010010101010101010101010101011111100011
1111010010010101010101010111101000100000
00000000000000011001100101010010101011111
```

The problem is that in the file 4 print substr($0, 2, index($0,"]")-2) > "fourth_"FILENAME the number with the sci notation with e does not get through. it works only as long as it is written without that . how can i cahnge the awk to also get the number in the way like 2.7e+7 or so

Comment: As I understand it, you didn't provide enough context, because with your example you could make it match like: `body  && /^\[[0-9]/`

Comment: could you show how the scrip would then look lik because i dont understand?

Comment: I mean, why do you want to match the whole number in exponential notation? Based in your input, you could match only a square bracket followed by a number. Much simpler.

Comment: yes..that would be great but how do I have to rewrite the awk thing then..that would be the answer...

Comment: try `index($0,"]")-1` ? Good luck.

Comment: so not print substr($0, 2, index($0,"]")-2) > but print substr($0, 2, index($0,"]")-1) > ..could you say if that is how you mea?

Comment: yes. As a note on being a good programmer, set yourself up so you can do quick tests. You should have been able to test my suggestion faster than wring back to me ! ;-) OK? Change your code per my suggestion and notice what change is made to the output. (you do understand what your code is doing, don't you?) ;-)  .... Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're trying to match E notation when your regex is looking for integers only.

Instead of:

```
/^\[[0-9]+\]/
```

use something like:

```
/^\[[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+(e[+-]?[0-9]+)?)?\]/
```

This will match positive integers, floats, and E notation wrapped in square brackets at the start of the line.

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/bB1gA1/3)